# How to setup clj-webdriver 0.7.2 with phantomjs

Tags: java, selenium, clojure, webdriver

I keep trying to set up phantomjs to create a web scraper, but I can't get the driver to work. I have added the lein dependencies like so:

```
  [org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server  "2.47.1"]                                                                                      
  [com.codeborne/phantomjsdriver  "1.2.1"
    :exclusions [org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server
    org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver]]
```

Then in my script:

```
   (ns vendors-api.routes.scrapers.resource
     (:require [clj-webdriver.core :refer [new-webdriver]])
     (:import                                                                                                                                                
       (org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs PhantomJSDriver)
       (org.openqa.selenium.remote DesiredCapabilities)))

   (def driver 
    (new-webdriver
      {:browser (PhantomJSDriver. (DesiredCapabilities. ))}))
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, compiling
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I expect your dependencies are incorrect/incomplete.

The following dependency list worked for me:

```
[clj-webdriver "0.7.2"]
[org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java "2.51.0"]
[com.codeborne/phantomjsdriver "1.2.1" :exclusions [org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java]]
```

And then

```
(require ' [clj-webdriver.core :as driver])
(def my-driver (driver/new-driver {:browser :phantomjs}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies as stated in the question are correct.

The final setup that got it to work in the script is as the following:

```
(:require [clj-webdriver.taxi :as taxi])

(System/setProperty  "phantomjs.binary.path"  "/path/to/binary")

(taxi/with-driver {:browser :phantomjs} (forms-to-evaluate)...)
```

Hope this helps someone else out there